# My application crashes when getting uri from user

Tags: java, android

I have a problem. I want to get the user of my app to select an audio file from storage using ACTION_GET_CONTENT, and my mainActivity crashes at that point.

```
       public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
            audioPath = intent.getData().getPath(); //This is were the crash happens
            audio = Uri.parse(audioPath);

        }
```

I'm new in android programming and there is surely something that I fail to understand. The error is as follows: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getPath()' on a null object reference

Comment: Starting the part where it is crashing, you could better do that in `onActivityResult`. You are now using the `Intent` you've just started an `Activity` with. An intent that you did not give data, hence when getting the path of the data you get an NPE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override on Activity Result in your activity. **DO NOT** use the same intent like you have done. You have to use the `Intent` returned in `onActivityResult` method. So your code should be:

**This should be your method to Pick an Audio**

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("audio/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1); //This 1 is your request code remember it
    }
```

**Then Override the onActivityResult method as**

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
       //The intent from this method is the one you need to get data from!
       if (requestCode == 1) {
       // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
               audioPath = intent.getData().getPath(); 
               audio = Uri.parse(audioPath);
              }
        }
     }
```

For more information on this method and receiving data from Activity Result [check this official training from Android](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html). Happy Coding!

Comment: It is called automatically when the user finishes picking something. This is only if you use `startActivityForResult` and not `startActivity`. Also remember you have override it only once. Even if you also want the user to also pick an image or something else, just pass a different request code. For your question we passed our request code as 1. And after picking audio we check first if the request code was 1. And retrieve the Value from Intent! So you if you want a user to pick an image use another `int` lets say 2 or something else!

Comment: Thank you very much!! Works like a charm.